# Equal width using flex and border-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using `box-sizing: border-box;` with varying `border` thicknesses within a flexbox. I want the elements within the flexbox to have equal widths, but it calculates the `width` of the element without the borders.

Here is an example: the `width` of my container is `100px`, so each element should be `20px`; however they are `19.2px` (x4) and `23.2px`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.container .block {
  height: 28px;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .block.selected {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="block">0</span>
  <span class="block">1</span>
  <span class="block selected">2</span>
  <span class="block">3</span>
  <span class="block">4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `box-sizing: border-box` is used to change the default CSS box model used to calculate `width` and `height` of the elements.

So would be like this:

- `total width` = `border` + `padding` + `content width`

  and
- `total height` = `border` + `padding` + `content height`

But that doesn't happen in `flex-grow`, but in `flex-basis`

Here is a good [**tutorial**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about flexbox

---

So you can use `flex:0 20%` instead of `flex:1`,

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.container .block {
  height: 28px;
  flex: 0 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .block.selected {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="block">0</span>
  <span class="block">1</span>
  <span class="block selected">2</span>
  <span class="block">3</span>
  <span class="block">4</span>
</div>
```

**Note:** if you have more elements than 5, then you can use `calc()` like this `flex: 0 calc(100%/8)` where 8 is the # of elements you will have

**Snippet with more elements**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.container .block {
  height: 28px;
  flex: 0 calc(100%/8);
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .block.selected {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="block">0</span>
  <span class="block">1</span>
  <span class="block selected">2</span>
  <span class="block">3</span>
  <span class="block">4</span>
  <span class="block">5</span>
  <span class="block">6</span>
  <span class="block">7</span>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, I like this answer best, even though they all do the same.

Answer (score 4):

The [**`flex-grow`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-grow) property does not set the width or height of flex items. It's job is to distribute free space in the container among flex items.

You have all items set to [**`flex: 1`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common), which is shorthand for:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

This distributes free space in the row equally among items.

**BUT** borders (and padding) are factored in separately.

`flex-grow` doesn't care about [**`box-sizing: border-box`**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing), because `box-sizing` applies to `width` and `height` calculations which, as mentioned earlier, are not functions of `flex-grow`.

Instead, use the [**`flex-basis`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property) property, which is equivalent to `width` (in a row-direction container) and will respect `box-sizing`:

```
flex: 0 0 20%;
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.container .block {
  height: 28px;
  flex: 0 0 20%; /* adjustment */
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .block.selected {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="block">0</span>
  <span class="block">1</span>
  <span class="block selected">2</span>
  <span class="block">3</span>
  <span class="block">4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the flex to one, you can set the flex-basis to 20% and then the width will be divided equally:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.container .block {
  height: 28px;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .block.selected {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="block">0</span>
  <span class="block">1</span>
  <span class="block selected">2</span>
  <span class="block">3</span>
  <span class="block">4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be setting a `2px` padding to the `.block` and removing it for `.selected`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.container .block {
  height: 28px;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
}

.container .block.selected {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="block">0</span>
  <span class="block">1</span>
  <span class="block selected">2</span>
  <span class="block">3</span>
  <span class="block">4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here `flex: 1;` change it to `flex: 1 0 20%;` even for more/less elements. no need to calculate the width using `calc` as others mentioned.

also just change this:

```
.container .block {
  height: 28px;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}
```

to:

```
.container .block {
  height: 28px;
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/4aww81wv/