# Adding padding to textarea increases its size in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to add padding to my textarea *without* it increasing its overall size but I can't seem to be able to achieve this... I have added `border-box` as a `box-sizing` value but it makes no difference.

Here is the Plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/64S6zBXBFvPcqUKqjFcO

If you play around with the padding value of `padding-3` class you will see that the textarea's total size. The goal is to keep the fixed size provided by the parent `div` and just add padding on the inside.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` is working fine in your code. The problem is you're using `flex-grow` to size your items. Since `flex-grow` doesn't actually set a width or height (it just distributes space), `box-sizing` doesn't apply. `box-sizing` works with `width`, `height` and `flex-basis`. (See my answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43807115/3597276) for a more complete explanation.)

Comment: Can you fix the plunkr provided? I'm trying to make it work but it doesn't seem to work as explained.. I removed `flex-grow` added `flex` yet it still keeps changing the textarea's total size when the padding changes...

Comment: You need to use `flex-basis`. `flex-grow: 1` and `flex: 1` are essentially the same in this context. Or, if you prefer, use the `width` and `height` properties, which will be recognized by `box-sizing`.

Comment: please take a look at the plunkr. I don't use `flex-grow`

Comment: What does that have to do with `padding` increasing the textarea's overall size? I don't have a problem with my textarea not filling the whole container div the problem is that when I add `padding` it increases the textarea's and the container div's size and disrupts the rest of the elements in the flexbox. Also note that I have given height to all required parent elements

Comment: Here you go bro. No more padding issues: https://plnkr.co/edit/Pv0GYsdOTziFATSGhf4v?p=preview